# Can't bind to 'heading' since it isn't a known property of 'page-header-component'

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular-module

```
-app
 - app.module.ts
 - app.component.ts
 - +home
    - home.module.ts 
    - home.component.ts
    - home.component.html
    - utils
        - page-header-component
    - reports
         - reports.module.ts
         - report.routing.ts
         - components
            - waybill-sign-off
 - +<other "features">
  - shared
  - shared.module.ts
```

And I use pager-header-component in home module as well as in reports module but I got this error.

Can't bind to 'heading' since it isn't a known property of 'page-header-component'.

here is my page header component:

```
export class PageHeaderComponent {
@Input() loading: boolean;
@Input() heading: string;
@Input() showSearch: boolean = true;
@Input() showPageSize: boolean = true;
@Input() showFilter: boolean = false;
@Input() showFilterIcon: boolean = false;
@Input() filterData: Array<FilterData>;

@Input() showDate: boolean = false;
@Input() showDD: boolean = false;
@Input() DDData: Array<any> = [];
```

Here is html:

```
<page-header-component [heading]="
   ('ADMIN.HEADER.WAYBILL_SIGNOFF'|translate)" 
   [showPageSize]="config.totalItems>10" [showDate]="true"
   [showSearch]="true" (searchChanged)="searchBy($event)" 
   (pageSizeChanged)="selectPagesize($event)" 
   (dateField)="onDateChange($event)">
```

I am using the PageHeaderComponent in both HomeModule as well ReportModule
but still getting the error Don't know why so?

Here is my Home module ts

```
    declarations: [
           .
           .
    WayBillDetailComponent,
    PageHeaderComponent,
    ]
```

Is there any need to export PageHeaderComponent?
This problem is not occurs only for the page header component it also comes for other component I guess there is some issue with struturing of modules I am unable to find from last few days can anyone help.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you add a declaration for `page-header-component` into app.module.ts or shared.module.ts? Seems like your component hasn't been imported and cannot be resolved.

Comment: Please check the file path

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding custom element then you need to specify `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in your `module` like:

```
import { NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
    ...Other Properties
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Comment: @Kiwi Rupela I have checked in stackblitz it's working fine??

Comment: I don't know I stuck on this issue from last few days still it showing the error
can't bind property.Not even the page-headercomponent it also showing the same error with othercompoenents i guess some structuring issue with modules. But still am not able to find this

Comment: @KiwiRupela where did you add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in which module??

Comment: In both HomeModule as well ReportModule.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define names in the parenthesis like this:

```
@Input('loading') loading: boolean;
@Input('heading') heading: string;
@Input('showSearch') showSearch: boolean = true;
@Input('showPageSize') showPageSize: boolean = true;
@Input('showFilter') showFilter: boolean = false;
@Input('showFilterIcon') showFilterIcon: boolean = false;
@Input('filterData') filterData: Array<FilterData>;
@Input('showDate') showDate: boolean = false;
@Input('showDD') showDD: boolean = false;
@Input('DDData') DDData: Array<any> = [];
```

Comment: Import PageHeaderComponent into HomeComponent